# Unable to switch to Nvidia 331 graphics driver

Tags: xorg, intel-graphics, gpu-driver, nvidia-prime, nvidia-settings

I'm trying to get HDMI video output working in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, which I've not had any luck with so far. 
So I installed the proprietary Nvidia 331 driver.

However the system still appears to be using the Intel driver as default

```
    lspci -k | grep VGA -A2
    00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 18)
    Subsystem: Dell Device 044f
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    --
    01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GT216M [GeForce GT 330M] (rev ff)
    Kernel driver in use: nouveau
    01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation GT216 HDMI Audio Controller (rev ff)
```

So I ran the Nvida X server settings utility

```
nvidia-settings
```

And it allows you to select the GPU you'd like to use. So I selected NVIDIA (performance Mode). However this didn't appear to work, and the selection remains on Intel (Power Saving Mode). I also tried the command line to switch it -

```
sudo prime-switch nvidia

/etc/modprobe.d is not a file
/etc/modprobe.d is not a file
/etc/modprobe.d is not a file
/etc/modprobe.d is not a file
update-alternatives: error: no alternatives for x86_64-linux-gnu_gfxcore_conf
```

Why is this happening, and how can I switch to the Nvidia driver? Or failing that I guess removing the Intel driver might be an option if anyone can recommend a good procedure for doing that?

Comment: Did you logoff and logon?

Comment: And please replace that weird perl script with `lspci -k | grep VGA -A2` output.

Comment: Yes, same problem.

Comment: Try #2 Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep VGA -A2` terminal command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nvidia driver is not installed according to your output.
Install it this way

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall nvidia-331 nvidia-prime
```

then reboot.

The correct commands for nvidia-prime are:

```
prime-select query
```

to see which adapter is in use.

```
sudo prime-select nvidia
```

to switch to Nvidia

```
sudo prime-select intel
```

to switch to Intel.

You need to logoff and logon to apply adapter switch.

Comment: Thanks. You're answer worked, but now when running with the Nvidia driver enabled, the machine slows down to a crawl, and becomes very hot. I've had to switch back to Intel mode.

Comment: @AndrewFielden  Maybe it makes sense to clean insides from dust.

Comment: This laptop is pretty old, could well be gunked up, but I really don't have time to take it to pieces. Plus some other strange things happened after I switched to Nvidia, like Wine didn't work, which I just can't live without. I had to re-install it. So back to Intel it is for me. Oh well, it was nice for a fleeting moment to have full 3D power.

Comment: This could be that wine was uninstalled. But there is no problem to install it back.

Comment: Ok, maybe I'll take this to pieces over the weekend. From past experience the cooling fan is not easy to get to. Can you think of anything else which could be causing this massive slow down? I've read that disabling VSync helps.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue. For me it happened right after a BIOS reset. I tried reinstalling the the nvidia drivers and reconfig step told me my motherboard was in Secure Boot mode  (which it had not been previously) and the driver can't be loaded without setting a password.  I switched the secure boot type from Windows to Other OS in my bios and it works again.  I suspect that turning off secure boot would work.

It was tailing the syslog while logging in that lead me to look at the graphics drivers (first and last lines):

```
[...] gnome-session[18439]: gnome-session-is-accelerated: No hardware 3D support.
[...] gnome-session[18439]: gnome-session-check-accelerated: Helper exited with code 256
[...] rtkit-daemon[17158]: Successfully made thread 18472 of process 18472 (n/a) owned by '1000' high priority at nice level -11.
[...] rtkit-daemon[17158]: Supervising 6 threads of 2 processes of 2 users.
[...] rtkit-daemon[17158]: Supervising 6 threads of 2 processes of 2 users.
[...] rtkit-daemon[17158]: Successfully made thread 18477 of process 18472 (n/a) owned by '1000' RT at priority 5.
[...] rtkit-daemon[17158]: Supervising 7 threads of 2 processes of 2 users.
[...] rtkit-daemon[17158]: Supervising 7 threads of 2 processes of 2 users.
[...] rtkit-daemon[17158]: Successfully made thread 18478 of process 18472 (n/a) owned by '1000' RT at priority 5.
[...] rtkit-daemon[17158]: Supervising 8 threads of 2 processes of 2 users.
[...] gnome-session[18439]: gnome-session-is-accelerated: No hardware 3D support.
[...] gnome-session[18439]: gnome-session-check-accelerated: Helper exited with code 256
[...] gnome-session[18439]: gnome-session-binary[18439]: WARNING: software acceleration check failed: Child process exited with code 1
[...] gnome-session[18439]: gnome-session-binary[18439]: CRITICAL: We failed, but the fail whale is dead. Sorry....
[...] gnome-session-binary[18439]: WARNING: software acceleration check failed: Child process exited with code 1
[...] gnome-session-binary[18439]: CRITICAL: We failed, but the fail whale is dead. Sorry....
[...] lightdm[17017]: /etc/modprobe.d is not a file
[...] lightdm[17017]: message repeated 4 times: [ /etc/modprobe.d is not a file]
[...] lightdm[17017]: update-alternatives: error: no alternatives for x86_64-linux-gnu_gfxcore_conf
```